# How to enable Intellisense for React in VS code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

Good day!

I have a VS Code.
But I can't turn on the Intellisense.
I've really tried, reading all the articles.

Is there a direct step-by-step solution on how to enable Intellisense for React?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe it's on by default. Are you sure of the issue you face? What is the issue, can you clarify?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots showing that Intellisense is not working? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Thanks.https://i.imgur.com/6reIsop.png